# WPF Panel where only one item is visible at a time (alternative to QML's StackLayout)?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have several controls and I want to show them only one at a time.
In QML there is a type [StackLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-stacklayout.html) which does that. But I haven't found a similar control in WPF.
I want to achieve the following:

```
<controls:StackLayout ControlIndex="{Binding CurrentlyVisibleControlIndex}">
    <controls:MyCustomControl1 />
    <controls:MyCustomControl2 />
    <TextBlock Text="Some text" />
    <Grid/>
</controls:StackLayout>
```

Then, from my ViewModel I want to dynamically change which control is shown.

**Answers:**

- [Direct answer to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67466523/7585517)
- [Better way of solving my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67468044/7585517)

Comment: It does not even occur to my head for what it might be needed ...
Most likely you are doing something wrong.
But if you need to solve your problem in this way, you can declare ListBox in the resources.
Fill it with the elements you need.
And in the Window set the output of the selected element.
Changing SelectedIndex - you will change the element displayed in the Window.

Comment: By the way, @EldHasp, why do you think that I'm doing something wrong? I want to have an application which in one of it's parts shows different controls depending on the state of my application. For example I want to show to the user either: List of processes, Error message in case processes hasn't been found, Progress bar. In the beginning I just used triggers to set Visibility setting to each control individually. But it caused a lot of code duplication. It is much better to have a control which abstracts out the logic "Only one is visible". Or could you recommend another approach?

Comment: You wrote about the ViewModel, so you are implementing MVVM. In MVVM, there is a strict hierarchy of View -> ViewModel -> Model. Real, original Data is in Model. The ViewModel converts them to a View-friendly type. But UI elements are only in View. The ViewModel, in theory, does not even need to know what type of View (WPF, Forms or Console), and not that directly control the UI elements in the Window.

Comment: One way to solve.
You create several different types in the ViewModel.
In the View, set a default DataTemplate for each type.
After that, simply by setting the binding of the Content to an instance of one of these types, you automatically get the necessary visual representation for it.
No "Voodoo Magic" with UI elements is needed for this.
This is a common and commonly used solution in WPF.

Comment: Another common WPF solution to this problem is to use a template selector.

Comment: @EldHasp that's what I just posted as answer

Comment: @voidengine, Yes.
And there is.
This way works much better for WPF.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I would go with a `ContentControl` templated based on the type of content you give it in your view model (rather than based on index). As the property changes, the appropriate template will be selected and displayed.

**XAML**

Resources define data templates for each kind of content in the control

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ContentXyz}">
        <controls:ControlXyz/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ContentAbc}">
        <controls:ControlAbc/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}"/>
```

**ViewModel**

The `Content` property holds the view model for the active control. When user actions or data changes require to display a different control, set it to the appropriate view model.

```
public IContent Content
{
    get => this.content;
    set => this.SetProperty(ref this.content, value);
}
```

And viewmodel classes for your inner user controls need to implement `IContent` (which is just a marker interface to describe the view model can be used in this place).

**More**

Also, frameworks like Prism help you compose views in more complex ways, giving you tools like automatic view discovery - see their [documentation](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/view-composition.html) for more.

Answer (score 1):

> But, I'm afraid that "abusing" ListBox for achieving my goal is not a good idea, because ListBox handles "Ctrl+LeftMouseCLick" which will deselect the item.

The ListBox needs to be hidden. It will not render.
Only its SelecteItem will be rendered.

Example for explanation:

```
<Window x:Class="StackLayout.StackLayoutWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackLayout"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="StackLayoutWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Enter the index:" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Grid.Column="1" Text="1" Margin="5"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Selected Item:" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox"
                 SelectedIndex="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox, Mode=OneWay}"
                 Visibility="Collapsed">
            <TextBlock Text="TextBlock" FontSize="20"/>
            <Button Content="Click me!" Padding="15 5"/>
            <Border Background="Blue" Width="100" Height="100"/>
            <Label Content="Label" BorderBrush="SkyBlue" BorderThickness="5"/>
        </ListBox>
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
            Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=listBox}"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

> Do you know if it is possible to create a custom user control which will contain the list and ContentPresenter so it can be used in the way I specified in my question?

In this case (as far as I understood the task), it makes no sense.
It is enough to override the default ListBox template.
In the example, to shorten the code, the template is specified in the Window resources.
But it is better to transfer it to the dictionary and connect it to the App.

```
<Window x:Class="StackLayout.StackLayoutTemplateWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackLayout"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="StackLayoutTemplateWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBox.Static.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFABADB3"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBox.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBox.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFD9D9D9"/>
        <Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle.StackLayout" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListBox.Static.Background}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ListBox.Static.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <!--<ScrollViewer Focusable="false" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>-->
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding SelectedItem}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ListBox.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ListBox.Disabled.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </FrameworkElement.Resources>
```

```
    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Enter the index:" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Grid.Column="1" Text="1" Margin="5"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Selected Item:" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox"
                 SelectedIndex="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox, Mode=OneWay}"
                 Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxStyle.StackLayout}"
                 Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="TextBlock" FontSize="20"/>
            <Button Content="Click me!" Padding="15 5"/>
            <Border Background="Blue" Width="100" Height="100"/>
            <Label Content="Label" BorderBrush="SkyBlue" BorderThickness="5"/>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Optionally, you can easily create a Custom Control from the ListBox with this template.
Although I do not see the point in this.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Do you know if it is possible to create a custom user control which will contain the list and ContentPresenter so it can be used in the way I specified in my question?

Comment: I have completed my answer.
Read there.

Comment: Once again, I strongly advise you to reconsider the solution you are creating.
You are about to modify the selected UI element in the ViewModel.
This looks very bad for WPF.
No UI elements should be created in the ViewModel, there should not be any calls to them.
ViewModel should only work with common CLR types.
If you describe why you need this, perhaps I will be able to suggest you a more typical for WPF solution.

Comment: thank you for your effort. By the way, using the way you have proposed I have found that it is possible to implement the StackLayout much simpler: [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67466523/7585517)

Answer (score 1):

> By the way, using the way you have proposed I have found that it is possible to implement the StackLayout much simpler

You can think of many options for implementation.
WPF is a very flexible tool.
And the task itself is relatively simple.

Here's an example of a Sharpe implementation:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace StackLayout
{
    public class StackLayout : ListBox
    {
        public StackLayout()
            => Loaded += OnStackLayoutLoaded;

        public static void OnStackLayoutLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox listBox = (ListBox)sender;
            Border border = (Border)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(listBox, 0);
            ContentPresenter presenter = new ContentPresenter();

            Binding snapsToDevicePixelsBinding = new Binding()
            {
                Path = new PropertyPath(SnapsToDevicePixelsProperty),
                Source = listBox
            };

            Binding selectedItemBinding = new Binding()
            {
                Path = new PropertyPath(SelectedItemProperty),
                Source = listBox
            };


            presenter.SetBinding(SnapsToDevicePixelsProperty, snapsToDevicePixelsBinding);
            presenter.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, selectedItemBinding);
            border.Child = presenter;
        }
    }
}
```

In my example, the default ListBox border is preserved, but if desired, you can also remove it.

**BUT** once again I would like to draw your attention to the fact that you have most likely chosen the wrong path for the realization of your task as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@EldHasp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67460678/7585517) I have found a much simpler solution:

```
<ListBox x:Class="MyProject.StackLayout"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding SelectedItem}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
</ListBox>
```

And it can be used in the following way:

```
<controls:StackLayout SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentlyVisibleControlIndex}">
    <controls:MyCustomControl1 />
    <controls:MyCustomControl2 />
    <TextBlock Text="Some text" />
    <Grid/>
</controls:StackLayout>
```